# Reinitialize Variable based on inherited type

Tags: java, variables, types, initialization

Is there a way to "reinitialize" a variable with a type which extends from the original type?

```
TileEntity te = world.getBlockTileEntity(x, y, z);
if (te instanceof TileEntityMonitorStorageFluid)
{
    TileEntityMonitorStorageFluid monitorTE = (TileEntityMonitorStorageFluid) te;
}
```

in this code i have to create a new var, is that the only way? Or could I "recycle" the te var? Always casting "te" wouldn't be good...

Comment: If I understand your question right then : no, `te` will always be of type `TileEntity`. If you want to use it as a `TileEntityMonitorStorageFluid` then you have to cast it every time or create a new variable `monitorTE` as you have done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the type of an existing variable.
On the other hand, I don't know why you would want to. Creating a new reference seems both clearer and easier, and the cost associated is minimal.

Comment: The cost may in fact be flat zero as even at the bytecode level, a location may be reused after the point where it's last accessed.

Comment: ok, thanks :D i will accept your answer after the limit is gone ("You can accept an answer in 3 minutes")